# Test Program in Delphi7 and XP on vmware, failed to connect socket

Tags: sockets, delphi, windows-xp, delphi-7

I try to run program in **Delphi7** and **XP** as virtual machine, the program include client and server and requires socket connections, but every time I try to run it, always showing error message like below.

I have already opened the **scktsrvr.exe** and I'm sure the port is right at both sides. The program need call the local port.

What confused me is that I tried with same environment and operation with my real PC and it works fine.

So I have no idea why I just can't run the program in a virtual machine. Or is there anything I should do if I want to use socket connections in a virtual machine?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Have found root cause, because of the setting of my client program.
I should **set the server IP as local IP** of my client program so it can connect the server part.
It's nothing about the virtual machine at all, though I don't need to do previous action in the real machine.
Whatever it has been solved.